# Prove that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \sum \frac {a_n} {2^n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \sum a_n/2^n$ converges.

My proof is below.  Please verify or improve it.

$\lim a_n = 0$, as $\sum a_n$ converges.  Therefore, there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $|a_n| < 1$.  For $n > N, 0 \leq |a_n/2^n| < 1/2^n$.  For any series $p_n, q_n$,  if $\sum q_n$ converges, and for all $n > N$, $0 \leq p_n \leq q_n$, then $p_n$ converges; consequently, $\sum |a_n/2^n|$ converges.  And since for any series $p_n$, if $\sum |p_n|$ converges, then $\sum p_n$ converges, therefore $\sum a_n/2^n$ converges.  QED.

---

### Update: Weaker Conditions

The condition $\sum a_n$ converges is unnecessarily strong. The proof works as long as $a_n$ eventually becomes bounded.

Comment: Looks good.  But you can simplify it.  Since $|a_n/2^n| \leq |a_n|$ for all $n$, the comparison test tells you that $\sum\limits_n a_n/2^n$ converges.

Comment: @D_S The comparison test tells $\;\sum\left|\frac{a_n}{2^n}\right|\;$ converges (since this test is appliable only to positive series), and since an absolutely convergent series converges, then we get the result for the series without the absolute value.

Comment: @D_S Wouldn't that require convergence of $\sum {\left| {a_n } \right|} $?

Comment: It is assumed that the series converges without absolute values. It does not imply that it also converges with absoute values (take for instance $a_n =(-1)^n/n$).

Comment: Oh I see.  Yah you're right.

Comment: Note that "Eventually becomes bounded" is equivalent to "is bounded" for sequences...

Answer (score 3):

Use Abel's test[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test): The series $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges and the sequence $\;\left\{\frac1{2^n}\right\}\;$ is monotonic descending to zero (and thus bounded), so the series $\;\sum\frac{a_n}{2^n}\;$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

Another proof: use the root test. We have

$\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq 1$

Since $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n$ converges. Thus, we have

$\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|\frac{a_n}{2^n}|} = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{|a_n|}{2^n}} = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \frac{1}{2} \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2} < 1$

So $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ converges.

Note: you cannot use the ratio test here because it may be that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}$ is undefined. But you can use the root test because $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ always exists or is infinity.